# Check a condition before saving a nested object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 model here : `NewWord`, `VerbForm` and `AdjForm`.

In `NewWord` model , I have a column `word_type` stored type of word: `Adj Noun Verb Phrase GenericWord`

Each NewWord may have 1 VerbForm or 1 AdjForm

```
Class NewWord < ApplicationRecord

    has_one :adj_form, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :verb_form, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :adj_form, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :verb_form, allow_destroy: true

   def self.types
        %w(Adj Noun Verb Phrase GenericWord)
   end
end

class NewWord::AdjForm < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :new_word
end

class NewWord::VerbForm < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :new_word
end
```

I use this form to create a word alongside with it forms

```
<%= simple_form_for new_word, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="error_section"></div>
    <%= f.input :word %>
    <%= f.input :kanji_version %>
    <%= f.input :word_type, collection: NewWord.types %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :verb_form do |v| %>
        <%= v.input :verb_type %>
        <%= v.input :dictionary_form %>
        # Other fields
    <% end %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :adj_form do |a| %>
        <%= a.input :adj_type %>
        # Other fields
    <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

My idea here is when user select `word_type` from dropdown, I can use Javasript to hide or show fields for `AdjForm` or `VerbForm`, or both. Then at submit, I only save `AdjForm` if new word's `word_type` is 'Adj', or `VerbForm` if `word_type` is 'Verb'.

So, how can I achieve this ? Since nested object saved automatically when I run this in new word `create` method: `@new_word.save.` ?

I have try `reject_if` but it only returns params for nested object only!

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :adj_form, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :not_adj

def not_adj(att)
    att['new_word']['word_type'] != 'Adj'   # Found out "att" here only has attributes of AdjForm , not NewWord !
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, before saving, check the word_type value and discard the params that you dont want to save.

new_words_controller.rb

```
def create
  prepare_params     
  @new_word = NewWord.new(new_word_params)
  if @new_word.save
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
end

private
def prepare_params
  params.delete[:verb_form] if params[:word_type] == "Adj"
  params.delete[:adj_form] if params[:word_type] == "Verb"
  params
end
```

This assumes you have whitelisted the parameters for new_word and its associations.